# Avoid space preceding a reference

Tags: spacing, cross-referencing, varioref

I use `\vref{something}` to reference to figures. As long as this is in regular text everything is fine. But When I surround this with brackets like this `(\vref{something})` then is the result is a preceding space in front of the reference:

Some text ( figure 1.1), some more ...

How can I avoid the space between the opening bracket and the word figure to get a result like this:

Some text (figure 1.1), some more ...

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}
 some text (\vref{fig:1}) some more ...



\begin{minipage}{.8\linewidth}
   \captionsetup{type=figure}
   \captionof{figure}{MWE}\label{fig:1} 
   \begin{Verbatim}[frame=single,baselinestretch=1,fontsize=\footnotesize]
something to show
   \end{Verbatim}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Did you consider using the `\cref` command provided by the `cleveref` package instead? I used that for my thesis and it didn't have spacing problems.

Comment: `\vref` doesn't add “figure”; if I type `some text (figure \vref{fig:1})` I get no spurious space. The `\vref*` command doesn't add the space (see section 2.2 in the documentation).

Comment: @egreg: Oh, you're right, I didn't compile it. Mainly because the question text implied something else. Anyways, `\cref` is still a good idea in my opinion. `;-)`

Comment: `\fref` from [fancyref](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyref) is very useful. [I used it for all the cross-references in my doctoral dissertation and didn't have spacing issues.] It has advantanges and disadvantages in comparison with [cleveref](http://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `\vref*` instead of `\vref`. The starred versions were created specifically for removing this *space* at left. View section 2.2 of the [varioref's documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tools/varioref.pdf).